# Using Karmarkar function on Scilab

Tags: scilab

I'm new to scilab and i was trying to work this out using karmarkar. But it's not working :(

`z= 3x11 + 3x21 + 2x31 + 5x41 + 4x12 + x22 + x32 + 2x42 + 2x13 + 2x23 + 3x33 +  x43`

Constraints:

```
3x11 + 3x21 + 2x31 + 5x41 ≤ 80
4x12 + x22 + x32 + 2x42 ≤ 30
2x13 + 2x23 + 3 x33 +  x43 ≤ 130
```

Production:

```
x11 +x12 + x13 = 10
x21 + x22 + x23 = 40
x31 + x32 + x33 = 50
x41 + x42 + x43 = 20
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved it, here is the answer:
[Answer containing codes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FnHfb.jpg)